# Memory issue when installing Unreal Engine 4

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have contacted the UE4 team and cannot get a response back nor from the official help forums, so I'm hoping someone here can help. I'm trying to install UE 4.21.0 but continue to get this error:

[image]

but when I check my storage capacity/availability, I have this:

[image]

I'm completely baffled by what's happening and have uninstalled/reinstalled the Epic Games launcher numerous times to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Note: Of course the error code the launcher provides is not a known error in their database, so that's not helpful either :(

Answer (score 0):

There should be space in the drive where your OS is installed , this means the drive your installing to has space but not your drive which has OS installed on it . Many softwares like photshop , maya , unreal etc need space in OS drive.